# What *precisely* is an "active" question?

Tags: discussion, questions, terminology

There are triggers in the SO system that move a thread into the active queue and all the other questions in the queue are pushed down. So in developer language, the active queue is a stack, right?

It's clear that editing the body of a question or answer will cause the thread to be pushed on to the top of the stack. What else?

Question: Is there a *complete* list of triggers such that the active queue can be precisely defined?

Secondarily, I always look at the 'new' queue and rarely at the 'active' queue, but I have a vague notion that most experienced users are doing the reverse. So I guess the question is: why use the active queue as your primary view when the 'new' queue is...  well... newer!  What's the advantage?

Answer (score 8):

I don't use the active queue but I can see it being useful in case you want to passively moderate (that is, without going to the review page). Useless edits, spammy/late/poor answers will show up there.

This list is not exhaustive and to be completed.

### Actions that trigger active

- Editing Q or A (even simple tag edits)
- Adding new A

### Actions that don't

- Upvoting
- Leaving comments
- Casting close/reopen votes

Answer (score 4):

I don’t know if a complete list of triggers already exists somewhere on Meta.SE, but here it is:

- posting a question
- editing *any* part of a question (title, body, tags)
- posting an answer
- editing an answer
- editing a deleted answer<sup>[1]</sup>
- applying a bounty
- reopening a question (not casting *a* vote, casting the *final* vote)
- the Community user bumping old unanswered questions randomly every once in a while

Most actions do not bump a question. That includes:

- commenting
- voting
- flagging
- accepting
- deleting answers through the review queue (if an answer is posted and subsequently deleted without anything happening in-between, the text on the main page chages from ‘answered *x* ago’ to ‘modified *x* ago’ with the same *x*.) or having a mod delete them.
- undeleting an answer<sup>[2]</sup>
- self-deleting an answer<sup>[3]</sup>
- deleting a question (does not make it active, it simply removes the entire thing from the page altogether.)
- awarding bounties

Personally, I like using the active tab, as it allows me to see what has *changed* and potentially adjust my votes or recomment accordingly. The new queue only shows new *questions* (to the best of my knowledge; but maybe it also shows new answers to questions) and thus I am likely to miss interesting answers or edits if I rely on it.

---

**Notes:**

[1]: Recently confirmed by a post over on chemistry. Answer was deleted, then edited. Editing showed up as an active bump of the question even while the answer was deleted.

[2]: According to pnuts in a comment.

[3]: An answer pnuts deleted *after* I answered [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/82364) did *not* make the question active again or change the active user. However, it did go from *answered* to *modified* although I did not edit my answer.

Comment: @pnuts To be perfectly honest, I’m not sure about active deletions (i.e. the user deletes their own question/answer). But review-queue-deletions do *not* create an entry.

Comment: @pnuts Actually, I just tested *self-deleting an answer* with this answer and it *didn’t* make the post active. So maybe there’s the additional caveat that you must not have been the last person being active.

Comment: I deleted *this post right here* ;) And then re-undeleted it.

Comment: Mental note to myself: Editing a deleted post and then undeleting it sets the timestamp to the time of *editing.* (Order was: deletion → other answer → editing → undeletion. Post was [this](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/61723/revisions).)